# How does a recursive function work in the example below?

Tags: python, python-3.x, recursion

```
def my_func(num):
   if num ==0:
         
           return 
         
   else:
            print(num)
            my_func(num-1) 
            print("The function is called recursively for",(num),"times")

my_func(7)
```

The results:

```
7
6
5
4
3
2
1
The function is called recursively for 1 times
The function is called recursively for 2 times
The function is called recursively for 3 times
The function is called recursively for 4 times
The function is called recursively for 5 times
The function is called recursively for 6 times
The function is called recursively for 7 times
```

I can understand the numbers 1 through 7 being printed but why do the numbers increase from "1 times" to" 7 times "in the statements? Once num = 0 doesn't the function "return" meaning doesn't it get out of the function? Why does it keep printing statements 1 through 7 and why are the numbers increasing? By the time it hits num = 0 , I would thionk it would get out of the function and never reach the print command?

Comment: Your output is not correct, at least, that isn't what I woudl expect nor what I get when I run your code. there shouldn't be numbers in between your `The function is called recursively. ..` lines. Are you **sure** this is your exact output?

Comment: `return` returns from the current function **invocation**. On recursion we have "nested" invocations of the same function.

Comment: Sorry. The output is:                                                                                                        7
6
5
4
3
2
1
The function is called recursively for 1 times
The function is called recursively for 2 times
The function is called recursively for 3 times
The function is called recursively for 4 times
The function is called recursively for 5 times
The function is called recursively for 6 times
The function is called recursively for 7 times

Comment: Visualize it : https://pythontutor.com/

Answer (score 2):

In essence, this is how your code works:
Note that the indentation is used to show what "function" it's running in.

```
my_func(7)
 - print 7
 - my_func(6)
   - print 6
   - my_func(5)
     - print 5
     - my_func(4)
       - print 4
       - my_func(3)
         - print 3
         - my_func(2)
           - print 2
           - my_func(1)
             - print 1
             - my_func(0)
               - return
             - print "Called... 1"
           - print "Called... 2"
         - print "Called... 3"
       - print "Called... 4"
     - print "Called... 5"
   - print "Called... 6"
 - print "Called... 7"
Finished everything
```

However, there shouldn't be anything in between the last print statements, like juanpa.arrivillaga had said.

Comment: I understand why the numbers 7 down to 1 are printed. But doesn't "return" get you out of the function and then there is no printing at the pont num = 0? Why does it keep printing?  After num = 0 the function "returns" , how does num go to 1 and then 2 and then 3.How is num increasing?   Thanks

Comment: @TonyCardinal Return only gets you out of the current running function. It doesn't get you out of every single functions it's being run in. Num is increasing because after calling the functions, it's ending the function. My answer has indentation denoting each function called. If you look at it, you can see that at the end of a certain function, another function finishes as well.

Comment: Thank you. So when num is 0 (after numbers 7 down to 1 are printed) the return command takes the control structure to the print command and at this point num = 1. Then num starts increasing by one each time. So in essence there is a loop around the single print statement that goes from 1 to 7 ? But I can't see why the print statement loops and how num increments

Comment: @TonyCardinal There isn't a loop at all. When my_func(0) is finished (returned), then my_func(1) is going to finish by printing "Called ... 1". Then my_func(2) will finish printing "Called ... 2" and so on. Calling a function regularly obstructs the current function from continuing which is why the function still has to finish the last print statement.

Answer (score 0):

The recursive functions are effectively nested, so you get your print line with `print(num)` called, for 7, then the function starts again with 6, so your `print(num)` is called again for six.

Once you get to 0, the bottom statement is called for each function as they're finished recursively.

So you for num = 3, you effectively get:

```py
my_func(3)

if 3 == 0:
    return 
         
else:
    print(3)

        if 2 == 0:
            return
        
        else:
            print(2)
            
            if 1 == 0:
                return

            else:
                print(1)

                if 0 == 0:
                    return
                
            print("The function is called recursively for",(1),"times")

        print("The function is called recursively for",(2),"times")

    print("The function is called recursively for",(3),"times")

# end of outer-most function
```

I don't get the individual increasing numbers printed between each line though

Comment: Thank you. I understand why the numbers 7 down to 1 are printed, but 2 questions: 1) Doesn't "return" get you out of the function all together? If it does why does it keep printing?  ANd 2) after num = 0 the function "returns" , how does num go to 1 and then 2 and then 3. Why is num increasing?  ty

Comment: Yes, return ends the function, but you're calling the function within another function, so you have `my_func(3)` which calls `my_func(2)`, which calls `my_func(1)`. When each return statement is hit, the current function ends, and continues through the function that calls it, returning each of them in turn